# How to use the same data to another page without recall service?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to pass the same data with more information to another page using click event on my item.

I tried to extend the class father to child but it's too slowly because the class is called a lot of many times..

The app is a dashboard with external widget imported in template html, each of them needs to use the same data.

I thought of using a container containing all the backend calls, for example using the module but without success.. any suggestion?

Comment: [RTFM](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

Comment: I need use provider in each component? The structure is: projejct.module -> project-details.component (with other component inside, so, it's is a container)

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose of a provider. Creating a service in Angular creates a Singleton, which acts as a state holder : by putting variables in this service, you make them available to any component injecting this service.

Comment: In this method i recall the same thing? My provider has function and api, if i use provider in each childs, am i recalling all contents contains in provider? Or i need to create multiple providers?

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing your needs, but most of the time you make the call once, store it in a variable, then use this variable in your application.

Comment: @mantegnous, create a "cache" service it's easy, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to just use something like ngrx/ngxs.
This will allow you to have a global state that you can access in every place of your application so that you can share state easily.

Answer (score 0):

services is usually how components exchange data in angular. but if your components have a parent-child relation you can use `@input()` . 
see https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

Maryannah, say that you can construct a "cache".
A function in a service normal is like

```
getData()
{
    return httpClient.get(....);
}
```

You can use a variable to store the result of httpClient

```
data:any[]
getData()
{
    if (!data)
       return httpClient.get(....).pipe(tap(result=>{
          this.data=result;
       }))
    return of(this.data)
}
```

So, the first time you subscribe to the service call to the server, the others one, you received an observable of the data yet readed

Answer (score 0):

> The Rx/js **BehaviorSubject** can solve your problem.  Angular good
>   practices recommends you to **avoid any logic inside components** that
>   it’s not directly related with the view. You should move all that
>   logic to services.
>   The **BehaviorSubject** holds the **value that needs to be shared with other
>   components**. These components **subscribe** to data which is simple
>   returning the **BehaviorSubject** value without the functionality to
>   change the value.

[Click here to know more about BehaviorSubject.](https://medium.com/@enriqueoriol/angular-service-component-communication-4933782af52c)